# Change Image display order by a button in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4, uiimageview

I want to change the order of two overlaped imagens in xcode, how can i do that?
I am working with button ids to call arrays and display two overlaped UIimagesviews . Now I want to change its order but I cant figure out which method I may use.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are either to add the views to their superview in a different order or to manipulate the `zPosition` property of the views' underlying `layer`s so that the layers you want on top have higher `zPosition`s than the ones you want beneath.

Comment: Ok, I did used zPosition and it worked pretty well! Thank You!!